# Running a shell script in mac terminal before building/launching android application

Tags: android, eclipse, terminal, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-tools

Here is what i want to achieve:-

I am having a shell script file. That file generates some files & folders and puts them in Finder where assets folder of my Android Application is present.

Every time i change something in my files that are generated using shell script i need to run that  script file from terminal, then build, install, run my Android Application.

Can anyone suggest me a way that before every build of android application my shell script executes and generate the latest files and those files then can be used by Android application.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want to rebuild the android app constantly.  While you could ssh into the mac and run a script, or even trigger it via TCP-over ADB or a log message caught by a daemon on the Mac, this whole approach might not be the best way.  How about providing the data over the network for runtime download/caching rather than compiling it in?  You could do this directly if the phone is on a network from which the Mac is routable, or via some internet fileserver.

Comment: actually i just want eclipse to run a script before running my android application

Comment: Before *running* it, or before *installing* it, perhaps with running automatically following?  If the later, it sounds like you might want to look into an ant build and read up on how to use ADB to install apps and then launch them via an Intent - basically duplicating what Eclipse/ADT does, but in scriptable form.

Comment: when i click Run As-> Android Application then before launching application my script should run

Comment: Oh, for that just add a custom pre-build step in the Eclipse project configuration.  Admittedly it will be a pain to figure out the details, but that's what that option is for.